# Excel-to activate/deactivate cells for user action based on dropdown selection

Tags: excel, input, drop-down-menu, cell

I am using a dropdown menu to select a type of equipment.
Based on the type selected, I am hoping to activate some cells for user input in them, while deactivate some other cells (or show "N.A." in them) to avoid user input.

I know how to use dropdown menu, however its the activate/deactivate cells for user input that is bothering me.

Kindly help.

Beginner here.
Thanks
Umesh

Comment: Multiply by 1 or 0 depending on the selection.

Answer (score 1):

Let suppose that in cell J6 there is a Data Validation for a list in Range("D2:D11")
which contains numbers from 21 to 30.

J6 Data Validation settings:

[image]

and in a cell for controlled input

[image]

For cells which want to be disabled change the True and False value in Source field.